# Displaying integer values on SliderRow

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, eureka-forms

I'm trying display the integer values instead of float. I tried the following:

```
    section.append(SliderRow() {
        $0.title = "Number of items"
        $0.tag = "numberOfItems"
        $0.minimumValue = 1
        $0.maximumValue = 10
        $0.steps = 10
        $0.value = 5
        $0.onChange { row in
            let isInteger = floor(row.value!) == row.value!
            if (!isInteger) {
                row.value = floor(row.value!)
            }

            let formattedString = String(format: "%.0f", row.value!)
            row.cell.valueLabel.text = formattedString
        }
    })
```

formattedString displays the values I want but I'm not able to display them on the screen. I can access all other attributes by row.cell. I change change the text colour, for instance, but not the text. I'm guessing I'm setting the text but it gets overwritten shortly.

Is there a way to make the slider show integer values?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you pls put some more code where you are changing `UILabel` text or something is dependent?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon: I've updated it with the full code I use for the row. I hope that's what you meant. I think that's all the relevant code I have but please let me know if I should look into something else.

Comment: Can you put some static `String` to check whether its displaying or not?

Comment: I tested with a print(formattedString) right where I set the valueLabel.text. It prints, for instance, "2" in the debug window but "2.0" in the actual label

Comment: and I tried setting a static string but it doesn't display. It may still be overwritten

Comment: So now, I hope the problem is with the other code which you haven't mentioned here.

Comment: There is no other code that is relevant to this row. I can change the colour of the cell so I now I can manipulate some values but it overwrites the text. Not displaying static string doesn't prove that it's setting it correctly but getting overwritten afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since Dec 2, 2016, there's a much simpler approach.....

```
$0.displayValueFor = {
   return "\(Int($0 ?? 0))"
}
```

(credit to https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/817 showing how to do it - and the associated fix)

This works great for showing an Int in the Eureka SliderRow as well as StepperRow
[See this picture of xcode Simulator showing Int values on StepperRow and SliderRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xyay.png)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I cloned the Eureka repository. Turns out I was right about overwriting the values. To test it I set the text to a constant value inside onChange handler, then added print statements in the SliderRow source code in valueChanged function:

```
    if shouldShowTitle() {

        print("current value: \(valueLabel.text)" )

        valueLabel.text = "\(row.value!)"

        print("updated value: \(valueLabel.text)" )
    }
```

The output looked like this:

> current value: Optional("xyz")
>
> updated value: Optional("3.0")
>
> current value: Optional("xyz")
>
> updated value: Optional("5.0")

So I created myself a SliderRowInt class that uses integers:

```
public final class SliderRowInt: Row<Int, SliderCellInt>, RowType {

    public var minimumValue: Int = 0
    public var maximumValue: Int = 10
    public var steps: UInt = 20

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
    } }
```

Now I'm using the integer version. Maybe not the most elegant solution but it worked fine for me.

There's a similar issue with the StepperRow which I solved the same way.

I checked in both classes to my cloned repository in case anyone encounters the same problem they can be found here: https://github.com/volkanx/Eureka/